# add some column and minus another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table `insert1` and `received1`
 in insert1 table have column and column name is `recharge_account`.
received table have one column and column name is `received_amount`.

I want to total `recharge_ammount - total received_amount` as dues.

```
recharge_Account       Received_Amount     dues
500              -        400               100

SELECT
    SUM(Account_recharge) AS `Total Recharge`,
    SUM(Amount_Received) AS `Total Received`,
    SUM(Account_recharge) - SUM(Amount_Received) AS dues
FROM insert1 i1
INNER JOIN received1 r1
```

i am not get to exact calculation .

Comment: what is your joining key, provide your table structure

Comment: You aren't joining ON anything..so what you get is a cartesian product (which you really don't want)

Comment: table name is -insert1 and another table name is received1

Comment: @Jitendra Kumar your last comment is not helpful. If you want to get the attention of a particular contributor prefix their user name with an '@' somewhere in your comment.

Comment: i want recharge_Acoount-received_amount=as dues

Comment: What do you get when you issue `desc insert1` and `desc received1` ?

Comment: Your code should work if you fix the join as mentioned in my comment and the answer from @Barbaros Özhan - if you are still having a problem then add table definitions and sample data as text to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a join condition such as `ON i1.id = r1.ins_id`, and `COALESCE()` function against null values :

```
SELECT
    SUM(COALESCE(Account_recharge,0)) AS `Total Recharge`,
    SUM(COALESCE(Amount_Received,0)) AS `Total Received`,
    SUM(COALESCE(Account_recharge,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(Amount_Received,0)) AS dues
FROM insert1 i1
JOIN received1 r1 ON i1.id = r1.ins_id
```

Comment: Probably correct(ish) but there's no evidence in the question that a join is possible.

Comment: @P.Salmon well, just a guess for table structures.

Comment: producing error normal by the join condition, since you didn't share the table structures @Jitendra Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `union all` and `group by`:

```
SELECT SUM(ir.Account_recharge) AS `Total Recharge`,
       SUM(ir.Amount_Received) AS `Total Received`,
       SUM(ir.Account_recharge) - SUM(ir.Amount_Received) AS dues
FROM ((SELECT Account_recharge, NULL as Amount_Received
       FROM insert1 i1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT NULL as Account_recharge, Amount_Received
       FROM received1 r1
      ) 
     ) ir
```

Actually, a `CROSS JOIN` also works:

```
SELECT SUM(i.Account_recharge) AS `Total Recharge`,
       SUM(r.Amount_Received) AS `Total Received`,
       SUM(i.Account_recharge) - SUM(r.Amount_Received) AS dues
FROM (SELECT SUM(Account_recharge) as Account_recharge
      FROM insert1 i1
     ) i CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(Amount_Received) as Amount_Received
      FROM received1 r1
     ) r;
```

The key in this case is that you need to aggregate *before* joining.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you don't need any kind of join.
You can sum over each column and return the 2 total columns in a subquery to subtract them:

```
SELECT t.`Total Recharge`, t.`Total Received`,
  t.`Total Recharge` - t.`Total Received`  AS dues
FROM (
  SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(Account_recharge) FROM insert1) AS `Total Recharge`,
    (SELECT SUM(Amount_Received) FROM received1) AS `Total Received`
) AS t
```